# How do I render different things in different render layers?

Tags: rendering, volumetrics, render-layers

I have an earth model with an atmosphere model around it. I want to render the earth in one render layer, and the atmosphere on another render layer. How do I set the atmosphere to render in the correct render layer? Sorry, I haven't messed with render layers that much so I'm a noob here.

Comment: Hi :). You simply check/uncheck collections you want to show in each render layer

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks! If you post this a a comment, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what the Collection checkbox is for.
You simply check/uncheck it to *Include/Exclude from View Layer*

[image]